# Fetch data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I retrieve data from column it returns only one row and duplicate it

and here's the problem :

[image]
  [image]

```
<div id="Mapel">
                        <label for="mapel">Mapel </label>
                        <button type="button" name="tambahMapel" id="tambahMapel"
                        class="btn btn-info" title="Tambah Mapel">+</button>
                        <select name="mapel" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Pilih...</option>
                        <?php
                        require_once '../class/mapel.php';
                        $mapel = new mapel(NULL,$tingkat);
                        $namaMapel= $mapel->tampil();
                        $idMapel = $mapel->getIdMapel();
                        foreach($namaMapel as $val){
                            echo "<option>".$val."</option>";
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

and this is the the method in the class i've used :

```
public function tampil(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "UjianWare");
        $query = "select nama_mapel from mapel "
                . "where id_tingkatan ='".$this->getIdTingkatan()."'";
            $hasil = $mysqli->query($query);
            return $hasil->fetch_row();
    }
```

Comment: remove the where condition `. "where id_tingkatan ='".$this->getIdTingkatan()."'"`

Comment: because in your  `id_tingkatan ` column have two ids SD have 3 rec and  SMA have 1 rec

Comment: i need to filter those actually

Comment: show me  `var_dump($this->getIdTingkatan())` result

Comment: here the result : string(2) "SD"

Comment: then SD have 3 rec not 4 rec it will return 3 and use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($hasil);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Md Nazrul Islam i have fixed my code with his help.
And this is for everyone that have found same problem with me i'll post my final code so everyone can understand

here's my method in my class that i have changed

```
public function tampil(){
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "UjianWare");
    $query = "select nama_mapel from mapel "
            . "where id_tingkatan =?";
        $hasil = $mysqli->prepare($query);
        $hasil->bind_param("s", $this->getIdTingkatan());
        $hasil->execute();
        $result = $hasil->get_result();
        while ($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
        return $arr;
}
```

and here the other one :

```
<div id="Mapel">
                        <label for="mapel">Mapel </label>
                        <button type="button" name="tambahMapel" id="tambahMapel"
                        class="btn btn-info" title="Tambah Mapel">+</button>
                        <select name="mapel" class="form-control">
                        <option selected>Pilih...</option>
                        <?php
                        require_once '../class/mapel.php';
                        $mapel = new mapel(NULL,$tingkat);
                        $namaMapel= $mapel->tampil();
                        $idMapel = $mapel->getIdMapel();
                        foreach($namaMapel as $val){
                            foreach ($val as $yo){
                            echo "<option>".$yo."</option>";
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use mysqli_fetch_assoc();  instead of fetch_row();
```

if it is not work then

```
$arr = [];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, name, age FROM myTable WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}
if(!$arr) exit('No rows');
var_export($arr);
$stmt->close();
```

https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: still the same as before

Comment: mysqli_fetch_row() [numeric only]
mysqli_fetch_assoc() [keyed only]
or
mysqli_fetch_array($result, $fetch_mode);                              http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: i've modified your code to be fit with my code but it's still not working. but my chrome dev tools said this between select syntax: 
                        array (
  0 =&gt; 
  array (
    'nama_mapel' =&gt; 'Matematika',
  ),
  1 =&gt; 
  array (
    'nama_mapel' =&gt; 'IPA',
  ),
  2 =&gt; 
  array (
    'nama_mapel' =&gt; 'PKN',
  ),
)
Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/E-SITO/script/form/inSoal.php on line 74

Comment: well good news i've got them but it's say 'array' 3 times just a little bit more i think, just how to converting those array to string

Comment: Okay it worked thanks for your contribution, it just a little bit polishment so it worked. Much thanks Md Nazrul Islam

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping through the result. You need to do

```
public function tampil(){
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "UjianWare");
        $query = "select nama_mapel from mapel "
                . "where id_tingkatan ='".$this->getIdTingkatan()."'";
            $hasil = $mysqli->query($query);
            while($row = $hasil->fetch_row());
            {
            $rows[]=$row;
            }
            return $rows;
    }
```

Using while loop you can add values in `$rows` array and return that array at the end of the function.

Comment: i've tried your approach but it still not working :(, it just returned a blank row

Comment: What do you get in $this->getIdTingkatan() ?

Comment: it will get the $tingkat in the declaration of constructor in here : $mapel = new mapel(NULL,$tingkat);

Comment: Can you please print your final query here?

Comment: what do you mean by final query?

Comment: echo $query; Print the query and send it here.

Comment: it returned error like this 

Catchable fatal error
: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in
/opt/lampp/htdocs/E-SITO/script/class/mapel.php
on line
78

Comment: Update `echo "<option>".$val."</option>";`  - with - `echo "<option>".$val['nama_mapel']."</option>";`

Answer (score 0):

try change query below way,

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="query";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//Associative array
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

//Numeric array

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);

//Free result set

return mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: try print query and copy and try in phpmyadmin.

Comment: sorry, i don't really understand here, what does i have to copy and paste in phpmyadmin?

Comment: print query and exxecute in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

By the way: You shouldnt call database in the function. use is 1time and call $conn when query data. it will be faster edit and fix when upload to host

Comment: thanks for your reccomendation :D i'll keep that in mind